# Google Maps API 3, c# MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello i have a little problem with latlng class.

When i use it like this:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.172414, 17.115294)
```

marker is in correct position.

But when i want to do that like this:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[0].latitude, @Model[0].longitude),
```

there is syntax error on comma and last bracket, and marker doesn't show. Browser debugger doesn't show any problems with js.

`latitude` and `longitude` are decimal. Is the reason that they have to much of numbers after comma? If yes , then it should be some errors in js, no syntax error in view.

Any idea what can be wrong? Or how to use own data from model in this class?

Comment: Why did you put the comma at the end? What's on the next line?

Comment: Another part of constructor map: map,  syntax error is at comma in brackets, after latitude and on bracket after longitude.

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like in the browser? Your code looks fine. Ignore any syntax errors Visual Studio might be showing. Razor Intellisense is buggy as hell. Just run your application and see how the generated javascript differs from the working code.

Comment: There is no difference in html when i use numbers or variables. Only one difference is on page. There is no marker. I can't find html code for marker. Google Maps Api prevents is blocking rmb click, so i was trying to get deeper in html until last highlightet element

Comment: Are you sure that the decimal values you have in your model are valid latitude and longitude numbers?

Comment: Yes. But i have idea. In database i have comma as separator, maybe there is problem? Nope. When data is retrieved from DB there is dot instead of comma.

Comment: I found the problem. VS is taking data with point, but in inspector  i can see that in js there is stil comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in separator. In DB there was comma, in VS there was point. But in razor in js there was comma again. I solved it like that.

```
var latit = @Model[0].latitude.ToString().Replace(',','.');
var longit = @Model[0].longitude.ToString().Replace(',','.');            
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({               
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latit, longit),
    map: map,
    title: '@Html.Raw(Model[0].name)',
    html: '<img src="/Img/'+@Model[0].id+ '_0.jpg" width="250px" height="250px">'
});
```